# He didn't know that Chatgpt "can" write an article - If the statement is a true thing it doesn't have to be shifted back to past tense?

Tags: tense, reported-speech

‎**Example 1**
He didn't know that Chatgpt "can/could" write an article.

**Example 2**
He didn't think that Chatgpt "can/could" write an article.

Are both of them correct English?

because if the statement is a true thing, it doesn't necessarily have to be shifted back to past tense?

Comment: This is covered in a lot of existing questions/answers e.g. [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/241613/reported-speech-backshifting-or-not) which says "If they were talking about something that is still true now, or is still expected to happen in the future, then you should use present or future tenses."