# sequence of tenses and will

Tags: sequence-of-tenses, backshifting

I'd like to know if my understanding is correct.

- She said "I will leave for the U.S."

This sentence can be rephrased in two ways, i.e.

1. She said she **would** leave for the U.S.
2. She said she **will** leave for the U.S.

If she has already left for the U.S., you say 1.

However, if she hasn't left for the U.S. yet, you can say either 1 or 2.

Am I right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reported Speech - Backshifting or not?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/241613/reported-speech-backshifting-or-not)

Comment: Note that if the speaker knows (or believes) that it's ***not possible*** for her to leave (even though "she" might not know that herself, and still thinks she will), he'd be very unlikely to use ***will*** (which implies an *inevitable* future, rather than just a *possible* one).

Comment: The would one implies an if: She said she would leave for the US [if x, that is not stated here occurs]. The same goes for will.